# Line break not working in Notifications android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, android-notifications

I'm trying to make a notification with a line break in .setContentText() but that is not working.

Builder of my notification

```
builder.setContentTitle("Notification")               
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif)
                .setContentText("Example1 "+"\n"+" Example2")  
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setTicker("testing it")
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

In the notification: `Example1 Example2`

but i need

```
 Example1
 Example2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, line breaks are ignored in `setContentText()`, as it is condensed. You can try `BigTextStyle`, example:

```
builder.setContentTitle("Notification")               
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                     .bigText("Example1\nExample2")
                )
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setTicker("testing it")
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigTextStyle for more information.

Comment: Tried using \n on Android 11 but it doesn't work. It shows up as \n. Same goes for <br>.

Answer (score 3):

**Default Notification Layout**

The main problem with this idea of multi-line text with the default notification layout is that in the underlying source code for the TextView has the following xml:

```
<com.android.internal.widget.ImageFloatingTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/notification_text_margin_top"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:gravity="top"
    <!-- Reason why a new line character won't work -->
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification"
    />
```

**Big Text Style**

As you can see the default view has hardcoded to a single line. So with that said, if you use the `BigTextStyle` as mentioned in the answer above it will work since the underlying xml uses the following layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/status_bar_latest_event_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="bigText"
    >
    <include layout="@layout/notification_template_header" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/notification_action_list_margin_target"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/notification_content_margin_top"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/notification_action_list_height"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/notification_main_column"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/notification_content_margin_start"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/notification_content_margin_end"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/notification_min_content_height"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <include layout="@layout/notification_template_part_line1" />
            <include layout="@layout/notification_template_progress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_progress_bar_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/notification_progress_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>
            <com.android.internal.widget.ImageFloatingTextView
               android:id="@+id/big_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/notification_text_margin_top"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/notification_content_margin_bottom"
             android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification"
              <!-- Reason why it works here -->                    
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ViewStub android:layout="@layout/notification_material_reply_text"
                android:id="@+id/notification_material_reply_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/notification_material_action_list" />
    <include layout="@layout/notification_template_right_icon" />
</FrameLayout>
```

So as you can see the view internally specifies `android:singleLine="true"` in the default notification layout case and `android:singleLine="false"` when using the BigTextStyle.

The simplest way to accomplish your task would be using the BigTextStyle but you can have much more control over the Layout if you use your own TextView inside of a layout file and call:

```
builder.setCustomContentView(RemoteViews remoteViews)
```

There is a good article by a GDE [here](https://medium.com/@britt.barak/notifications-part-3-going-custom-31c31609f314) explaining how to use RemoteViews if you so choose to, it is relatively straight forward.

Good luck and Happy Coding!

Answer (score -2):

You can try to execute a line break by using the strings.xml to declare your text. Go to res/values/strings.xml in your project folder, and then declare the String as

```
 <string name="example">Example1 \n Example2</string>
```

Then go to your activity,and in place of your text, write
`R.string.example` or you can get the String using `String example = getString(R.string.example)` and use the String variable inside your setContentText.

```
.setContentText(R.string.example) or .setContentText(example)
```

Infact, not only this instance, but you should declare all your String values in the string.xml.
Refer to the String resources [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#java) for further knowledge.

Comment: I don't think this would work, because setContentText() would still ignore the `\n` line break.